# Forwarding third domain url to directory in the main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, forwarding

Hullo,
I would like to forward accesses to subdomain blog.xxx.yy to directory www.xxx.yy/blog possibly keeping the originary address in the address field of the browser. How may I do it?
I tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.taxiprofessional\.net
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ blog [NC,L]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Are `blog.xxx.yy` and `www.xxx.yy` pointing to same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Yes, I set up a test case at taxiprofessional.net: both blog.taxiprofessional.net and www.taxiprofessional.net point to the same address, as you may see.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.taxiprofessional\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.taxiprofessional.net/blog/$1 [L]
```

It should redirect `blog.taxiprofessional.net` to `http://www.taxiprofessional.net/blog/` and and `blog.taxiprofessional.net/about` to `http://www.taxiprofessional.net/blog/about`

Comment: Yes, but it changes the url. You may see it at work at:
http://blog.taxiprofessional.net

Comment: Sorry, removing the `R,` in it will stop that.

Comment: Nope, I did just that but as, you may also see, the effect is unchanged.

Comment: Actually the other approach given by anubhava attains just that, with only drawback of the wrong access to the css files.

Comment: Yes, I just temporarily set the other configuration and you may have a look. I will reset it in ten minutes not to confuse users.
http://blog.taxiprofessional.net

Comment: You might need to add either a base to the head tag or `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to before the rewriterule.

Comment: Ok, in fact I added a base command in a previous attempt and it does the job. As for the latter solution, should I apply it to your solution or the anubhava's one?

Comment: You would be adding it to anubhava's one. If using base works, then go with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.taxiprofessional\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).*)$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, the difference is that in this way the url is not changed but for some reasons the CSS get totally screwed up. Possibly because they link to a top directory like if they were in the sub-directory, but the call actually happens from above. I do not know for sure. Is there a fix without copying everything on the top directory or put <base> commands in all files?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.taxiprofessional\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).*)$ /blog/$1 [NC,L]
```

It does the job. The .htaccess reading was at None on the httpd.conf. Now, as you may see it works, with just a catch about the position of the CSS that I assume a simple base may fix.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by establish a few virtual domains.